# Eclipselink: No suitable driver found in glassfish while it works in JavaSE

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I'm trying to create EntityManager in my webapp, but it's failing with:

No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql:://localhost/database

However the same persistance unit and the same code for creating  EntityManager works when I run it as JavaSE console application (from main() ).

Googling gave me several common problems causing that error:

- JDBC url is wrong
  Shouldn't be since it works from main
- JDBC Driver is not in the class path
  I can create a Class object using `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");` for the driver so I think it is in the classpath.

Other things I tried:

- I thought maybe the driver jar from glassfish/lib and the webapp/WEB-INF/lib are conflicting somehow so I tried with both of them together and separately, no luck.
- Recreated a small new webapp hoping the problem will go away, it didn't :-)
- Inject @PersistanceUnit - also didn't work, don't know is it the same issue or I didn't use it properly as I'm still learning about injection and EJBs

Thanks

Full error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database Error Code: 0
```

Here is the code:

ManagedBean in webapp:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TestBean {
private String entry;
private String driver;

public String getFromDatabase(){
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Unit1");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    EntityOne one = new EntityOne();
    one.id = 1;
    one.entry = "Bla bla";


    em.persist(one);
    tx.commit();
    em.close();

    return "done";
}

public String createDriver(){
    try {
        Class d = Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        driver = d.getName();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        driver = "Class not found";
        return "";
    }

    return "";
}


public String getDriver() {
    return driver;
}

public void setDriver(String driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public String getEntry() {
    return entry;
}

public void setEntry(String entry) {
    this.entry = entry;
}
}
```

Same code working in main:

```
public class Standalone {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Unit1");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    EntityOne one = new EntityOne();
    one.id = 1;
    one.entry = "Bla bla";


    em.persist(one);
    tx.commit();
    em.close();


    }
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="Unit1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>com.test.EntityOne</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="darko"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sifra"/>

        <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="PostgreSQL"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Try calling `createDriver` on the first line.

Comment: I tried already, didn't make a difference, but thanks.

Comment: Does adding `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver` set to `org.postgresql.Driver` make a difference?

Comment: It did, it works as expected now, thanks a lot :-) Though I must wonder why was that necessary as I remember it working in the past on other projects and never using that property.

Comment: The DriverManager can sometimes determine the class to use from the URL.  Looks like this time it could not, likely because of how and where the driver is in relation to the DriverManager and EclipseLink class.

Answer (score 0):

Place the posgres jdbc driver into the lib of glassfish. Its something like this.

```
[glassfish_home]/glassfish/domains/YOUR_DOMAIN/lib/
```

Also, restart the server after this.

Comment: Tried, didn't make a difference, tnx for the suggestion.